# Link ASP.NET Identity Users to Books Table

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've used the default WebApi template with Individual Authorization for my project.
I've successfully registered accounts, and edited the model and controller so that the UserName is stored in the Username field instead of the email, which is how it is by default.

I am trying to create a Book table with the following model :

```
public int Id { get; set; }
[Required]
public string Title { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }
public int Ratings { get; set; }

// Foreign Key
public string Username { get; set; }
// Navigation property
public Guid Guid { get; set; }
```

I want to use the UserName as the foreign key since it is unique. Can anyone tell me if this is correct. I'm not sure the navigation property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For having a Foreign Key, the standard examples say that you should have something like this:

```
public Guid UserId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey(nameof(UserId))]
public virtual User User { get; set; }
```

This allows you to use `UserId` as the `Foreign Key`, at the same time the entire User object is lazily available to you. You could use this property to access the `Book.User.Username` in your code.

It makes little sense to have a column containing the the actual `Username`s. Tomorrow, if you wish to have the user's `Email`, you will have to add another column in your Books table. But with the above example, you merely need to access `Book.User.Email` in the code.

(Tip: Using the `Id` column is fast is it is the `PK` in the Foreign table and hence `Indexed`.)

(Tip2: Avoid `Guid` as the type for Id column. Personally, I use `long, which is more efficient with respect to indexing and has a reasonable range)

Comment: Okay. That makes sense. Thanks for clearing up the confusion.

Comment: Small problem regarding `public virtual User User { get; set; }`. I've attached a screenshot. Which one should I use? [Screenshot](http://imgur.com/a/EGO3v)

Comment: I think it should the `IdentityUser` from the `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework`

Comment: Okay, I did that. But when I'm trying to create a async controller for the Book model class in the ApplicationDbContext I get an error: `"The type of property 'UserId' on entity 'Book' does not match the type of property 'Id' on entity 'IdentityUser' in the referential constraint 'Book_User'."`

Comment: Okay, so the `User` basically should be of the type of entity belonging to the Foreign Table. In your case it seems to be the `Book_User`